# Tracing file creation via dynamic analysis of iOS application (using Frida)

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, analysis, nsfilemanager, frida

Using FRIDA (http://frida.re), I'm debugging/reverse engineering an iOS app. The aim is to trace every file or folder created on the device by the app during runtime. So far I've tried running this javascript-snippet I found online via Frida:

```
var fileExistsAtPath = ObjC.classes.NSFileManager["- fileExistsAtPath:"];

Interceptor.attach(fileExistsAtPath.implementation, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
      var path = ObjC.Object(args[2]);
      send("[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:] " + path.toString());

    },
  }
});
```

The javascript code works, however the function that is traced is only checking whether a file exists or not (as stated in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1415645-fileexistsatpath). I'm not an experienced iOS developer, so if anyone have suggestions for iOS libraries and functions that are used to create (or write data to) files/folders by apps, I would be very grateful. I have found the "createFileAtPath" method in the Apple Developer documentation, but I'm unable to find any instance of this method in the running app.

Comment: There are multiple ways an app can create files, probably more than you can cover. Also an app creates files internally by the SDK that you might never know the method used. 

What is the overall goal? 

You might want to consider using FSNotifications to see what files are created and changed.

Comment: Thank you. The overall goal is to see which user input/actions triggers the creation of files / folder on the filesystem.

Comment: Have you tried by tracking open() from fcntl.h (man 2 open) ? For example, frida-trace -i open -p PID ...  open() should be used by most higher level functions that create files. I am not totally sure though, other can correct me. You could create a test app and create files using different methods, e.g. `[NSString writeTo:...]` and others, and see if you track them. From Frida JS API, you should use something like `Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName('libc.so', 'open'), ...`, but on IOS replace `libc.so` with the correct .dylib library, which maybe is libc++.1.dylib.